# android: listview and linearlayout padded from the edges of parent layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, nine-patch

[image]

So, I want to create a layout with listview and Linearlayout clearly specified with the image.

The padding i.e. required from all the edges of the device is important for me and this should work in a responsive manner for different devices it should be padded from various sides.

Could I Use **Nine patch** in this case , if yes how?

How could I achieve this , any skeleton layout will solve my problem.

Comment: I don't get the problem/question. You are trying to use images as padding? or ? you want different padding depending on screensize?

Comment: I want padding based on screen size the next part is just a suggestion regarding 9 patches.

Comment: padding based on screensizes can be done be suplying different layout files based on screensizes. Don't use Nine patches for this

Comment: Got the problem solved with nmw's suggestion for using layout_margin. I had another issue where I am inflating the listview with an xml but it doesnt fill the row of listview but getting some margin, what could that be?

Comment: Open an new thread on stackoverflow and post some code related to the listview and its adapter. Post the link in the comment below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get that spacing you should use **margin**, not padding.

Here's a solution:

```
<RelativeLayout        
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mylistview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/listview_height"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/standard_margin"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/mylistview"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/standard_margin>

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

This sets a fixed value for the `ListView`'s height, and makes the `LinearLayout` automatically resize to fit the remaining space (because of layout_below).

Then create a dimensions file in res/values:

E.g.

dimens.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <dimen name="listview_height">200dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="standard_margin">30dp</dimen>

</resource>
```

To support different screen sizes you can have different dimensions in other folders such as /res/values-large, /res/values-xlarge etc.

Comment: Thanks for your right answer , its not padding but the margin similar to the web. I want to ask one more suggestion regarding an issue in layouts but don't want to start a new question for the same could you help me in that